# Why there are minus signs in rotation of exact triangle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A\xrightarrow{u} B\xrightarrow{v} C\xrightarrow{w} A[-1]$ be an exact triangle.

Consider rotation $B\xrightarrow{v} C\xrightarrow{w} A[-1]\xrightarrow{-u[-1]} B[-1]$ and $C[1]\xrightarrow{-w[1]}A\xrightarrow{u}B\xrightarrow{v} C$

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why $A[-1]\to B[-1]$'s morphism is $-u[-1]$? Should this not be $u[-1]$ only? Similarly why $C[1]\to A$ is $-w[1]$ instead of $w[1]$?

Ref. Weibel, Homological Algebra, Chpt 10, Example 10.1.6(Rotation)

Comment: What is $\ A[-1]\ $ and $\ u[-1]\ $ ?

Comment: @WlodAA part of the definition of a triangulated category is the existence of a translation functor $T$ that is an auto-equivalence. In this case, for example,  $A[-1]=T^{-1}A$.

Comment: I've +ed your comment. However, your q. didn't include mathematicians who would have a good chance to answer your q. even if they don't know apriori the respective definitions. *** Also, it's nice to provide certain service to participants by educating them in your speciality.

Comment: these signs appear for some deeper reasons that come form the closed monoidal structure on the category of chain complexes. it would be quite a mouthful to explain here, but there is a lovely "paper" on signs in homological algebra and spectral sequences http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/papers/signs.pdf

However, a lot of it is so one can use the Koszul sign rule as easy (i.e. try to be able to handle morphisms as easy as possible by shoving as many minus signs as possible into the differential and stuff) as possible.

Comment: @WlodAA I'm not the OP.